# Windows phone 8 app messagebox causing media player pause

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xna

When In my app messagebox poping up causes background media (from mediaplayer) pausing,after I press ok it resumes back,Is it normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is normal. It is because the MessageBox you are using is synchronous and waits for input on the UI thread. There are a few async MessageBoxes out there that you can use like Coding4Fun or Telerik. You can also make the [Windows Phone Toolkit CustomMessageBox async](http://visuallylocated.com/post/2013/06/13/Making-the-Windows-Phone-Toolkit-CustomMessageBox-async.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the information,I will try to do a async messagebox for my purpose.